# Finding radius of a circle from a tangent and a secant

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

We know how long the tangent line is and I found out that DC is 4, which would make EC 10. I can't figure out what to do next. I've tried to use similar triangles (BEA and BAC) and found no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point):
$$
AB^2=BC\cdot BE\implies BE=\frac{AB^2}{BC}=18\implies EC=BE-BC=10.
$$
Recalling that the diameter drawn through the midpoint of a chord is perpendicular to the chord one obtains  by [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) for the circle radius $R$ the value:
$$
R^2=PD^2-\left(DE-\frac12EC\right)^2+\left(\frac12EC\right)^2=4^2-(6-5)^2+5^2=40.\tag1$$

---

> For explanation of (1) see figure below. I hope the relations: 
>   $$EQ=QC=\frac12EC;\quad QD=ED-EQ;\\
> PQ^2=PD^2-QD^2;\quad PC^2=PQ^2+QC^2$$ 
>   are clear enough.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you set up the Pythagorean theorem equation. What does each term in the equation stand for? (PD, DE, and the 1/2 EC's squared) How did you find out what to input into the equation and what were the steps?

Comment: @Potatoz4u I have added some detais. Let me know if there is a need in further explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved using Pythagorean theorem and probably wouldn't have been able to solve it without your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the chord theorems for the intersection points both inside and outside the circle, we have

$$DE\cdot CD = (r-PD) \cdot ( r + PD)\implies 6CD=(r-4)(r+4)
$$

$$BA^2 = BC \cdot ( BC + CD + DE)\implies 12^2=8(8+CD+6)$$

Eliminate $CD$ to obtain $r = 2\sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\triangle PDC $ and $\triangle EPC $ are similar. Because both tiangles are iscoseles . So( $\frac{4}{r}=\frac{r}{10}$ )
                  $r= 2\sqrt10$